# Gerrit - Current branch and remote branch have diverged

Tags: git, branch, gerrit

Firstly, I push my commit to GERRIT for review

Secondly, my teammate verified my commit and submit to repo

Thirdly, I sync with command git fetch，and I found my current branch and remote branch have diverged when I check status

I want to know how does it happened and how to avoid it, can somebody help me

***All command I have ran***

`git add app/Http/Controllers/StatisController.php`

`git commit`

`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<remote_branch>`

After the commit submitted

`git fetch`

`git status`

And I got the message as following:

On branch client
Your branch and 'origin/remote_branch' have diverged, and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.

(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Comment: Without more information it's difficult to tell, your changeset may have been automerged by gerrit, or rebased by your teammate.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ The operation is very simple: 1. git add git add app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php  2. git commit 3. git push origin master  4.  The commit has been submitted, git fetch & git status, and I got the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Root Cause

With the info we have it's impossible to know but, probably, your commit was automerged or autorebased by Gerrit. Changes are automerged/autorebased depending of the [submit strategy](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/concept-changes.html#submit-strategies) configured in each project. To know which submit strategy a project is using do the following:

1. Click on ***Projects*** > ***List***
2. Find the project
3. Click on project name
4. Click on tab ***General***
5. See the ***Submit Type*** field

### How to avoid issues with this

Forget your local branches (remove them) after your commits are merged in the remote branch (submitted on Gerrit) and always start a new branch to work on new changes.

To work on change 1

```
git fetch
git checkout -b LOCAL-1 /origin/REMOTE
# Work on the change
git add .
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/REMOTE
```

If you want to work on change 2:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b LOCAL-2 /origin/REMOTE
# Work on the change
git add .
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/REMOTE
```

If you need to rework the change 1:

```
git checkout LOCAL-1
# Rework the change
git add .
git commit --amend
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/REMOTE
```

When change 1 is merged (submitted) on Gerrit:

```
git branch -D LOCAL-1
```

In resume: your local branches should not follow the remote branches.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new for Gerrit and I do not know how Gerrit does when my commit was submitted. Why does Gerrit will automerge or autorebase and result diverged

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: The Submit Type is **Cherry Pick**, and my local code repo is exactly the same as remote code repo, the diverged commit was the code that I just commit, why diverged happened; and I also paste all command I have ran

Comment: Please read the "Cherry Pick" item of the "submit strategy" in the Gerrit documentation link I have posted: "Always cherry pick the patch set, ignoring the parent lineage and instead creating a new commit on top of the current branch". In other words: with this submit strategy set every time someone click on the "Submit" button a NEW COMMIT is created. This explains why your commit (in the local branch) diverged from the merged commit (in the remote branch). What to do? Delete your local branch and start a new one based on origin/BRANCH like I've suggest in the answer.

Comment: I probably understand that.It seems like I need to delete local branch and start a new one every time I sync with remote repo, maybe a bit complicated. No matter what I have got it and thanks

Comment: When you get more experienced It's totally possible to work without even creating a local branch specially to make small changes. You just checkout origin/BRANCH (detached HEAD), make the change and push to Gerrit.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options if your branch has diverged.

1. Merge the remote branch into your local one. This is the default behaviour of `git pull` but this will result creating a merge commit and clutters the history of your branch.
2. Rebase your local branch onto the remote one (`git rebase origin/the-branch`). This is my prefered option as it creates a clean easily readable commits history.

Comment: In fact, I resolve with `git rebase`. But I will get diverge while sync with remote repo every time, and I have to do rebase again

Comment: Not necessarily, you only diverge when someone pushed some changes while you also did some changes on the same branch. A good practice is to always fetch before comitting and if you are collaborating on the same branch to push often.

Answer (score 0):

The command to sync the current branch is `git pull`. `git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git merge`. You've already ran `git fetch`, so you can call `git merge` manually (let's say the current branch is `master`):

```
git merge origin/master
```

Or you can forcibly move the branch:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Or you can just run `pull`:

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: The command `git merge` can resolve the problem, but this method will result a new merge commit

Comment: @pain Not necessary. Fast-forward merge doesn't produce a commit at all. And of course `git pull` either performs fast-forward merge or real merge producing a merge commit.